# How to allow user to Connect Twitter account (get access token permanently) after he is logged-in to next-js app using next-auth's Google provider?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth

**Scenario :**

1. User is logged in on my app using Google oauth (using next-auth Google provider)
2. Now I want to give user the option to connect their Twitter account permanently on Button click(i.e. store their Twitter access token somewhere in db).
3. Once the user connects and authorises my app using Twitter, my app can perform action on Twitter on behalf of the user.
4. Next time, user just has to login on my app using google auth, and he should be able to access and perform action (use Twitter API) without authorising again from twitter page

**Main Question:**

Q1. Does next-auth support different providers on different page? If yes, then how to call signIn() for each of them individually?

Q2. Can I implement point 2 to point 4 in next-auth? If yes, then how? If No, then what's the alternative approach?

Comment: access tokens expired after an hour you would need a refresh token stored so you can request a new access token